# HAL_SetDate sets the year to wrong value

Tags: stm32, hal, stm32f0, cubemx

I'm using STM32F030RCT6 with CubeMX. Device is a datalogger and RTC is the main thing that cannot fail. On [Errata Sheet](http://www.st.com/resource/en/errata_sheet/dm00091791.pdf) there is something about RTC Shadow Register.

I configured CubeMX to not generate `MX_RTC_Init()` function and it has been working normally so far. (I'm using LSE)

I need to update the time/date from GSM time but when I set the year to **18** with `HAL_SetDate()` and after a small delay I read with `HAL_GetDate()`, `sDate.Year` gave me **20**. Apart from `Year`, the other values are correct.

What I tried:

- Used LSI
- while (HAL_SetDate != HAL_GetDate) HAL_SetDate(ActualDate)
- First `HAL_GetDate` then `HAL_SetDate`

I got no progress and thing even got worse like `Month` = 56, `Day` = 45 etc.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The value `WeekDay` must be set to a value between 0 to 7

I had the same problem. I found that the problem was: **Not setting a value to `WeekDay`**. When creating a struct `RTC_DateTypeDef` in a functions scope, the field `WeekDay` gets a random value. I discovered that: **The value `WeekDay` must be set to a value between 0 to 7, if it is out of this range, it can change the year**.

### Explanation:

The code for setting the date in function `HAL_RTC_SetDate`:

```c
if (Format == RTC_FORMAT_BIN)
{
    assert_param(IS_RTC_YEAR(sDate->Year));
    assert_param(IS_RTC_MONTH(sDate->Month));
    assert_param(IS_RTC_DATE(sDate->Date));
  
    datetmpreg = (((uint32_t)RTC_ByteToBcd2(sDate->Year) << 16U) | \
                  ((uint32_t)RTC_ByteToBcd2(sDate->Month) << 8U) | \
                  ((uint32_t)RTC_ByteToBcd2(sDate->Date)) | \
                  ((uint32_t)sDate->WeekDay << 13U));
}
else
{
    assert_param(IS_RTC_YEAR(RTC_Bcd2ToByte(sDate->Year)));
    assert_param(IS_RTC_MONTH(RTC_Bcd2ToByte(sDate->Month)));
    assert_param(IS_RTC_DATE(RTC_Bcd2ToByte(sDate->Date)));

    datetmpreg = ((((uint32_t)sDate->Year) << 16U) | \
                  (((uint32_t)sDate->Month) << 8U) | \
                  ((uint32_t)sDate->Date) | \
                  (((uint32_t)sDate->WeekDay) << 13U));
}
```

- `Date` occupies bits 0-7 (8 bits): two BCD digits.
- `Month` occupies bits 8-12 (5 bits): two BCD digits but the left digit can
  only be 0 or 1 -> 5 bits is enough.
- `WeekDay` occupies bits 13-15 (3 bits): one BCD digit with value range 1-7 -> 3 bits
  is enough.
- `Year` occupies bits 16-24 (9 bits).

When `WeekDay` is greater than 7, the MSB is 1 and it overlaps with the LSB of `Year` and can change it (if the LSB is 0).

Comment: This is now (at least in STM32F4xx HAL V1.8.2) asserted in the HAL. If you have `USE_FULL_ASSERT` on (which is actually usable these days!), `HAL_RTC_SetDate` will fail if `WeekDay` is not **1** through 7. It's not clear to me what happens if you set it wrong.

Regardless, if you don't have `USE_FULL_ASSERT` on, then this answer probably still stands.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue with setting the year value after using `HAL_SetDate()`. Wrong values was read with the `Hal_GetDate()` function.

`MX_RTC_Init()` checks first a particular value in a RTC BKP register to know if a Reset occurred on the RTC domain. It prevents from setting again the time and date if it has been already done.

I finally did the same and tadaaaam for the first time I'm reading a good year value of 18 !!

```
if(HAL_RTCEx_BKUPRead(&hrtc, RTC_BKP_DR10) != 0x32F2){ // Mandatory: workaround found ?
    if(HAL_RTC_SetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BIN) == HAL_OK){
        if(HAL_RTC_SetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BIN) == HAL_OK){
             HAL_RTCEx_BKUPWrite(&hrtc,RTC_BKP_DR10, 0x32F2);
        }
    }
}
```

I do not understand precisely why it works, I'll ask on ST forum and edit this answer as soon as I know.

In the meantime could you check if it works for you too ?

Comment: Thank for reply. I already changed HW with external RTC but I will try. What MCU are you using? Because my MX_RTC_Init() also not working properly it resets the RTC everytime.

Comment: I'm using an STM32L476 with the driver revision v1.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `WeekDay` parameter to a valid value.