# STM32F051 HAL_RTC_SetDate not setting Year correctly

Tags: stm32, hal, real-time-clock

So I am using a smart phone application to set the `Time` and `Date` of the RTC on the micro-controller. The RTC runs on LSE.

The formatting of the string that I sent over to the micro-controller is correct. I can be certain of that when I set the relevant variables on "Watch 1". I am using Keil uVision 5.

```
/** 
  * @brief  RTC Date structure definition  
  */
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t WeekDay;  /*!< Specifies the RTC Date WeekDay.
                         This parameter can be a value of @ref RTC_WeekDay_Definitions */

  uint8_t Month;    /*!< Specifies the RTC Date Month (in BCD format).
                         This parameter can be a value of @ref RTC_Month_Date_Definitions */

  uint8_t Date;     /*!< Specifies the RTC Date.
                         This parameter must be a number between Min_Data = 1 and Max_Data = 31 */

  uint8_t Year;     /*!< Specifies the RTC Date Year.
                         This parameter must be a number between Min_Data = 0 and Max_Data = 99 */

}RTC_DateTypeDef;
```

So my command that I sent over actually sets the DD/MM/YY and of course the time as well but I have no issues with time.

After setting it and then calling `HAL_RTC_GetDate` and `HAL_RTC_GetTime`, everything is correct except for the `Year` field.

My command that I send over will always be year 2018 however the `HAL_RTC_GetTime` function will always return a higher and random value such as 24, 22, 21 and 19. Occasionally, after sending a few times of the same command but with different mins and seconds, the Year will go back to 18...

What could be the issue? Also, must I set the `WeekDay` parameter since I only set the `Day`, `Month` and `Year`.

Thank you!

*I have a function that will help me take the last two digit of the year 2018 which I send over and it will push the value of 18 to the micro-controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HAL\_SetDate sets the year to wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264383/hal-setdate-sets-the-year-to-wrong-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've decided to try setting the `WeekDay` parameter by hardcoding it first. So I sent the exact same command of setting the `Date` and Time with Date in DD/MM/YY format to the micro-controller and my read back values are correct so far. I followed this link given by A.Rech:

[HAL_SetDate sets the year to wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264383/hal-setdate-sets-the-year-to-wrong-value)

Even with repeated sending of the same command with the same DD/MM/YY but with different time, my read back values from `HAL_RTC_GetDate()` is correct so far! I hope this would be the case and not just coincidence.

Thanks!

*Just to add on. Prior to hardcoding the `WeekDay` param. Whenever I send the command with DD/MM/YY to the micrco-controller multiple times with different Time values set while the DD/MM/YY the same. The read back value of the `WeekDay` param will be a random number, in my case a single digit number not more than the value of 7.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the definition of your struct.
The year is uint8_t only so maximum is 255.
If you read the comment behind the definition, the year is limeted to be between 0 and 99.

Best thing is writing just 18 instead of 2018 to your RTC.

Comment: Just saw your command is DD/MM/YY so this would be ok. Later on you have written 2018, what did you write to the RTC?

Comment: Hello, 

I did adhere to the format that they needed.

//TIME=DD-MM-YY,HH:mm:ss

The above is the format which I send my command over

Comment: Have you set the time using HAL_RTC_SetTime(RTC_HandleTypeDef *hrtc, RTC_TimeTypeDef *sTime, uint32_t Format)? What format did you pass to the function? Same as with GetTime?

Comment: Yes, I always run HAL_RTC_SetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BIN) and then HAL_RTC_SetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BIN) for that function that I am using. In the same function I have also assigned values to:

sDate.Date
sDate.Month
sDate.Year
sTime.Hours
sTime.Minutes
sTime.Seconds

Comment: Look at this thread, they seem to have the same problem: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264383/hal-setdate-sets-the-year-to-wrong-value)

Comment: Hi, I will take a look at it. Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found that the problem was not setting the `WeekDay` (when creating a struct `RTC_DateTypeDef`, the field `WeekDay` gets a random value). **The value `WeekDay` must be set to a value between 0 to 7**.

See my full answer for a similar question with explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54236587/10927863